# Web API HttpGetAttribute errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm making an API for accessing a SQL Server database. I've written the models and classes that I need, so now need to create a controller for joining everything up.

My controller code at the moment is

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EPOSDatabase_API.DataProvider;
using EPOSDatabase_API.Models;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EPOSDatabase_API.Controllers
{

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoryController : ApiController
{
    private ICategoryDataProvider categoryDataProvider;

    public CategoryController(ICategoryDataProvider categoryDataProvider)
    {
        this.categoryDataProvider = categoryDataProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> Get()
    {
        return await this.categoryDataProvider.GetCategories();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<Category> Get(int Category_ID)
    {
        return await this.categoryDataProvider.GetCategory(Category_ID);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody]Category category)
    {
        await this.categoryDataProvider.AddCategory(category);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task Put(int Category_ID, [FromBody]Category category)
    {
        await this.categoryDataProvider.UpdateCategory(category);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task Delete(int Category_ID)
    {
        await this.categoryDataProvider.DeleteCategory(Category_ID);
    }
  }
}
```

However for the lines

`[HttpGet("{id}")]`, `[HttpPut("{id}")]` and `[HttpDelete("{id}")]` I get an error

> 'HttpGet/Put/DeleteAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Why is this error occurring, am I missing a `using` reference, perhaps?

Comment: tried to import `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` instead? seems conflicted with `System.Web.Mvc`..

Comment: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore;` and `using System.Web.Http;` – You are mixing ASP.NET Core and classic ASP.NET MVC. That’s a very bad idea and will break. Choose just one.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, I tried that, but when trying it is said "The type or namespace 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore"

Comment: For MVC (not Core) you can use a Route attribute to specify route parameters.

Comment: @poke does it matter which one I use? What is the difference?

Comment: They are very differently built frameworks, see [this comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework) for details.

Comment: @poke Thanks, seems like Core is the one I need, as a result of which, I get "The type or namespace 'Route' could not be found" along with  "The type or namespace 'HttpGet' could not be found"... How do these bits need to change to match MVC Core?

Comment: If you have started with an ASP.NET MVC project (not Core), then you’re best off starting from scratch and manually moving over your logic. Some things translate 1-to-1 but a lot of things will not, starting with the project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Category> Get(int id)
{
    return await this.categoryDataProvider.GetCategory(Category_ID);
}
```

or

```
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<Category> Get(int id)
{
   return await this.categoryDataProvider.GetCategory(Category_ID);
}
```

should both do the trick.
ASP.NET Web API know how to match your method signature to the incoming request.
or if you want to change the default behavior you must keep the variable name as the parameter name in the method signature.

you can read more about Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: well, the docs says you can [add a constructor parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_HttpGetAttribute__ctor_System_String_) to it for specifying route template.. though i'm afraid probably the underlying mechanism did not allow using `{id}` only..